# How do I add or remove collection document fields server side in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to add or remove fields to a doc before insert or update in the allow or deny methods. I had presumed that the transform function would provide the needed functionality.

The meteor docs state

> "An optional transformation function. Documents will be passed through
>   this function before being returned from fetch or findOne, and before
>   being passed to callbacks of observe, allow, and deny."

Whenever I tried to transform and return the doc from the function either from allow or deny the transformed version of the document was not what was inserted into the mongodb. I tried transforming via 2 strategies.

**Strategy 1**

```
var ts = new Date(); 
return _.extend(_.pick(doc, 'name', 'discounts', 'locations', 'url_map', 'client_updated_td', '_id'), {   created_td:
ts,   updated_td: ts,  });
```

**Strategy 2**

```
// Discountsroutings.fields is in /lib/Discountroutings.js
Discountsroutings.fields = ['_id', 'created_td', 'updated_td', 'client_updated_td', 'name', 'discounts', 'locations', 'url_map'];

// this is in /server/discountsroutings.js var ts = new Date();
doc.created_td = ts; doc.updated_td = ts; return _.each(doc,function(value, key, list){  
  if(Discountsroutings.fields.indexOf(key)  == -1 ){
    delete doc[key];   
  } 
});
```

Neither worked.  In both cases fields were not removed though fields were added.

Interestingly, I tried the same two strategies from inside an insert allow and an insert deny and only Strategy #2 worked.  So, for now I am just using **Strategy #2** inside Deny insert/update methods.  Works fine and isn't that difficult to wire up.

Am I doing this correctly? I want to add or remove fields from a collection server side the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steeve have you tried my collection-hooks package? Sounds like what you need

Comment: I did and it looks awesome. Right now I don't want to take on any packages because I am concerned about future dependency issues.  As indicated above Strategy #2 works great.  I had figured Strategy #1 would work.  I had also figured it would work in the allow or deny transform function but neither strategy does.

Comment: Don't worry about future dependency issues, packages are as easy to update as any code you'll make for Meteor. And they often make things MUCH easier.

Comment: Steeve, collection-hooks just wraps the insert/update/remove on Meteor.Collection or the _collection property (client vs server). The only risk is that the property name _collection changes in future Meteor updates.

Comment: Another thing I should mention -- you don't need meteorite either. My personal choice is to use straight-up meteor, and I recommend mrt vs meteor to clients depending on various circumstances. To use collection hooks, you could download as a zip from GitHub and stuff it in your local `packages/` folder then `meteor add collection-hooks`, or even set it up as a git submodule.

Comment: i resisted bcuz i worry about relying on packages...but this package rulez!

Answer (score 0):

you seem to know the list of fields you want to remove. So why don't you use [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) and [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) to add and remove fields?

Comment: That is for removing the fields from the mongo collection schema.  The question is really how to add or remove fields prior to insert or update.  For example, you may want to add a created time date stamp and you definitely want to prevent malicious attempts to add fields and data.

Answer (score 0):

Recently needed to do the same thing and found no example here... thought I'd share how I did it:

Using

- https://atmospherejs.com/matb33/collection-hooks
- http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/

  ```
  Prospects.before.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {


  //check existence of other segment property and make sure to delete it if segment is updated from 'Other...' to something else
  if (is.existy(doc.other_segment)) {
      var segment = Segments.findOne({_id: modifier.$set.segment});

      if (is.not.undefined(segment) && is.not.empty(segment)) {
          if (is.not.equal(segment.name, 'Other...')) {
              Prospects.update( {_id: doc._id} , {$unset: { other_segment : '' } } );
          }
      }

  }});
  ```

Hope this helps! :)